# How to prevent users to delete their Approval Task created from SharePoint Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

Users can delete their task when task is assigned to them from SharePoint Workflow. 
And I created a new permission level same as Contribute except delete action and apply to the task list. But again assigned users can delete their task.

I don't know what happened it stuck me here for a while. 
And for info I have checked the option in approval task workflow in designer like below in setting section.
[image]

Any help would be appreciate.